# Bibtex cite an (online)article or url from a online version of a magazine

Tags: bibtex

I am new to using to Latex and Bibtex.There is a (online)article in the following link, which I want to use in Bibtex:
http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.de/Magazin/2013/05/Distributionen-fuer-den-Raspberry-Pi-im-Ueberblick

Its possible to Use it in a style sheet with the following parameters:

- url
- title
- the journals name
- the authors
- the edition (in this case 05/2013 )

(maybe with aditional informations)

Comment: Use `biblatex` for that: it defines a `url` field for all entry types, in particular for `@article`.

Comment: Use the natbib package, which I found relatively straightforward for when new to LaTeX. Here's [a reference page](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_natbib). In the long run biblatex may be more flexible.

Comment: @Bernard - The claim that the `url` field is recognized for all entry types holds for bibliography styles such as `plainnat` and `unsrtnat` as well.

Comment: @Mico/ I know that, but I personally never used  `natbib` so I don't know enough details to be helpful.